# Removing bullet in unordered list for switches

Tags: html, css, input, switch-statement, html-lists

I'm trying to display multiple rounded switches in an unordered list. It looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8Eij.jpg 
Now I noticed, that the bullets of the unordered list are still there and I tried to remove them with `list-style-type: none;`. However this would kinda collapse the whole list and the switches are overlapping. I just started html/css so I don't really know what is going on there. 
The HTML

```css
.switches{
    border: 1px solid white;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
    width: 200px;
}

/*
.switches ul{
    list-style-type: none; not working
}
*/

.switches ul li{
    margin: 13px;
  
}

.switch {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-flex;
    right: 20%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 23px;
    float: right;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.switch span{
    color: #cdcbcb;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #1a1919;
    margin-left: 47px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(17px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(17px);
  transform: translateX(17px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="switches">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                <div class="slider round"></div>
                <span>Test</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                <div class="slider round"></div>
                <span>Test2</span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of "collpasing" is due to your `position: absolute` in the styles of `.switch`.

When `list-style-type: none;` no content is inside each `.li`. And therefore `.li` will occupy **no** space.

I did some changes on the `.switch` styles:

```css
.switch {
    /* position: absolute; */ 
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    right: 20%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 23px;
    /* float: right; <-- you don't need this when `relative`. Otherwise items will still "collpased". */
}
```

For your list style:

```css
.switches ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

The following snippet is the modified version:

```css
.switches{
    border: 1px solid white;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
    width: 200px;
}

.switches ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.switches ul li{
    margin: 13px;
  
}

.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    right: 20%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 23px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.switch span{
    color: #cdcbcb;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #1a1919;
    margin-left: 47px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(17px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(17px);
  transform: translateX(17px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="switches">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                <div class="slider round"></div>
                <span>Test</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                <div class="slider round"></div>
                <span>Test2</span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was it :D

Answer (score 1):

This is what I suggest:

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/a5nuqtkL/

You'll need to work out the checkbox styling (https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/bGEqEdB) - but here's how the layout bits should work. Make sure you progressively enhance these - instead of creating something that isn't accessible. (you need official labels etc)

```css
* { /* https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.field-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: auto;
}

.field-list input, .field-list label {
  display: block; /* inline by default */
}

.field-list .field {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.field-list label {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="field-list">

  <li class='field'>
    <input id="one" type="checkbox">
    <label for="one">Thing one</label>
  </li>
  
  <li class='field'>
    <input id="two" type="checkbox">
    <label for="two">Thing two</label>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `list-style: none;` or `list-style-type: none;` with `display:flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` for avoiding overlapping of items.

```css
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.switches{
    border: 1px solid white;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
    width: 200px;
}

/*
.switches ul{
    list-style-type: none; not working
}
*/

.switches ul li{
    margin: 13px;
  
}

.switch {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-flex;
    right: 20%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 23px;
    float: right;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.switch span{
    color: #cdcbcb;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #1a1919;
    margin-left: 47px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(17px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(17px);
  transform: translateX(17px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="switches">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                <div class="slider round"></div>
                <span>Test</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                <div class="slider round"></div>
                <span>Test2</span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```